# Why did they skip the iPhone 9?

Tags: iphone

Is this known? If not, then what are the most popular theories or explanations for why they went straight from an 8 to a X?

Comment: Asking “why Apple does something” is considered off-topic.  Please see [How to Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) found in our [Help] for full details.

Comment: They also skipped the 2, because the 3 wasn't so much a 3 as a 3G, for the phone tech.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The accepted theory about this is that the year that it came out was the 10-year anniversary of the first iPhone. Most people are of this opinion.

Source: [huffpost.com](https://www.huffpost.com/archive/au/entry/why-apple-skipped-iphone-9-and-went-straight-to-iphone-x_au_5cd3838ce4b0acea9501fdb9)